# How to Put List of Items into Scenario.context for Specrun

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, specflow, specrun

I need to put list of items into Scenario.Context.
For example i have

```
IList<IWebElement> test = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(""));
```

and it will return more than one values evertime and now if i want it to be stored in Scenario.Context how would i do that ?

Comment: You can just place the list into the scenario context. See [my other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33096025/97614)

Comment: Worked nicely thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass variables as array specflow c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080841/pass-variables-as-array-specflow-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

See sample for ScenarioContext scope:
 https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext.Current

For Feature scope it is similar

Store:
ScenarioContext.Current.Add(name, test);

Using:

IList < IWebElement > test 
= (IList < IWebElement >) ScenarioContext.Current[name];